# Testing Video with Rspec and Capybara

Tags: html, testing, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

I was wondering if anyone knows how to test html5 video with a flash fallback with rspec/capybara? We need to support a variety of browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE7-11), and each one has its own quirks: Firefox requires either ogg video or flash, and various older browsers don't support html5. On top of this, we are using both iframe embeds and a video tag, and things go wacky inside these elements, and I'm not sure how to get at them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try selenium?

Comment: We'll be using the selenium driver, but our QA team decided against it for some reason I'm not acquainted with.

Comment: Try with page-object gem.

Answer (score 0):

Working with videos is tricky across multiple browser but you can easily check if the video exists on the page. I'd also recommend taking a screenshot of the pages that have videos because it's much easier to look at screenshots than manually test a bunch of browsers.

Here's some example ruby that checks for both types of video:

```
begin
   page.should have_css("object[class='flash video']")
rescue RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
   page.should have_css("iframe[class='html5 video']")
end
```